# Laravel 6: API PUT and DELETE method does not work

Tags: php, routes, laravel-6, laravel-passport

I am just learning laravel resource methods to build a basic API. Below is the code of my file that shows all the API routes.

```
//get data
Route::get('data/{id}','Api\Controller@show');

//post data
Route::post('data','Api\Controller@store');

//update data
Route::put('data/{id}','Api\Controller@update');

//delete data
Route::delete('data/{id}','Api\Controller@destroy');
```

In this API routes `GET` and `POST` work fine but `PUT` AND `DELETE` method does not work and it thowing a **`403 Forbidden`** error.

If anyone knows how to slove this problem, it would be a great help. Thanks!